# Image and visibility in php

Tags: javascript, php, css

I tried finding this question in Stack Overflow but since didn't find it I am asking it:

I am trying to create a program that has a table with 2 columns. In the first column I have an image and the second column is empty. When I click on the image I want to see a URL in the second column.

And if I go to the second row and click the image then the url in first row dissapears and the second row url will appear. Here is my code but due to some reason that I do not know it is not working. I appreciate if someone could give any comments or any suggested code:

```
<table class="table tb-mytable">
<?php if($as_result){?>
    <td class="img-parent"><img src="../../uploads/<?=$as_result['as_asset']?>" style="width:<?=$width/2?>px; height:<?=$height/2?>px;" class="<?=$as_result['as_id']?> test"  /></td>
    <td class="<?=$as_result['as_id']?> iframe-link">
        <?php echo htmlentities('<iframe frameborder="0" width="'.$width.'px" height="'.$height.'px" style="overflow:hidden;padding:0px; margin:0px;" scrolling="no" src="'.$site_url.'stream/?q=c_'.(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'mycamp')).'|p_'.$_SESSION['code'].'|a_'.$as_result['as_id'].'"></iframe>                            ');?>
    </td>
```

Here is the JavaScript part:

```
$('.img-parent').click(function(){
    $(this).next('td').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

And here is the css:

```
.iframe-link{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of rendered html... perhaps on codepen.io or jsfiddle.net? Because in my test, I'm not seeing the same behavior you are: http://jsfiddle.net/gxeezdc4/1/

Comment: Hi @DanielRippstein, unfortunately I can not show any screenshot as it is not my project and I am not allowed to give screenshots, but what I see is an image and a URL infront of it which should not be there. The URL is only shown if the image is clicked. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on this... do you _want_ it to hide all other second columns when you click?

Comment: @DanielRippstein when the page is open we should only see the images in the table. When we click on each image we want to see the url. and if we click on the next image we want to see the url in-front of the image but the previous url should be hidden. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not working for you because in your `click` function, you just change the `visibility` of the adjoining second column that contains the URL. You however first need to hide the URL that was last visible. One work around could be:

```
 $(function() {
 //Hide the second column as soon as the document loads
 //Although you shouldn't require this since your css already does it
 $( "td.iframe-link" ).css('visibility', 'hidden');

  //The click functions that toggles the visibility of the adjacent element
  $('.img-parent').click(function(){
     //Assuming the class for the adjoining td i.e the second column is iframe-link
     //Hide all such elements first
     $( "td.iframe-link" ).css('visibility', 'hidden');

     //Display the relevant element
     $(this).next('td').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });

});
```

Hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, Thank you for the recommended suggestion. It works but not completely. When the page is open, i see all the urls and images, but when i click on the images then all the urls disapear and only the url related to that image will be appeared. So what we need to do it to hide the whole urls before any click is done. Which I already have done through my CSS. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did all the URLs appear in your earlier code as well? Since you have explicitly defined it in the `css` stylesheet, it should get computed accordingly. One workaround is obviously since you're using JQuery, you could explicitly set the `visibility` to `hidden` on `document.ready`. Please see my edited answer for the same.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense... your CSS (which you wrote in your original post) is supposed to hide that already. Did you remove it? Because Vivik's suggest works fine for me, if I leave your CSS in: http://jsfiddle.net/gxeezdc4/2/

Comment: @DanielRippstein, exactly my point. I would also not want to reset the `visibility` to `hidden` in the js when the same element is explicitly styled in the stylesheet already.

Comment: Guys, now the code is working fine after I used the edited code of Vivek. I get your point now. Thank you so much for your support :)

Comment: But I have a question, why the first version of Vivek code didn't work? With setting visibility to hidden, it should have worked. I appreciate if you could tell me what do you think is the reason of not working in the first version of Vivek code?

Comment: @MaryJane, Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you as it might also help others in a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: @VivekPradhan I marked it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MaryJane, DainelRippstein put together an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gxeezdc4/2/) with the code I had written initially and it worked. And it should work for you as well. That's why I had asked if the URLs in your case were getting hidden in your initial code as well.

Comment: @VivekPradhan, I looked at the code and understood it. Thank you for the effort.